# NullPointerException at DruidDataSource.getConnectionInternal

Tags: java, spring-boot, druid

I get **NullPointerException** on DruidDataSource.getConnectionInternal(DruidDataSource.java:1704)?

Below is the full stacktrace.
Can you help me to understand the issue?

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### The error may exist in com/byai/line/dal/mapper/RegistrantMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.byai.line.dal.mapper.RegistrantMapper.deleteByCallerAccountId
### The error occurred while executing an update
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:199)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.delete(DefaultSqlSession.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnectionInternal(DruidDataSource.java:1704)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnectionDirect(DruidDataSource.java:1402)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.dataSource_connect(FilterChainImpl.java:5059)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.logging.LogFilter.dataSource_getConnection(LogFilter.java:886)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.dataSource_connect(FilterChainImpl.java:5055)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.stat.StatFilter.dataSource_getConnection(StatFilter.java:680)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.dataSource_connect(FilterChainImpl.java:5055)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:1380)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:1372)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:109)
    at com.baomidou.dynamic.datasource.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:42)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:82)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:68)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:336)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:93)
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.doUpdate(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
    ... 106 common frames omitted
```

Comment: A stacktrace is not a question - please see [ask] and edit your question accordingly. You need to explain what you are trying to do, and show a [mcve] that would allow other people to reproduce the issue.

Comment: first resolve the Null pointer exception.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please go through some standards while post the question.

Comment: Which version of [druid](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.alibaba/druid) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved, the reason is I made a mistake of driver-class-name, my config is the password of the datasource, so it throw a init exception, but I missed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Q2t.png)